# A silly question about $C_0$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $Z$ be a closed subspace of $X$.  The inclusion map $i: Z \hookrightarrow X$ induces a map $C_0(X) \to C_0(Z)$ (via pullback).  My question is simple: what is the kernel?  The answer should either be $C_0(X - Z)$ or $C(X - Z)$ and I think I know which one is correct.  But I need a sanity check, so I thought I would post the question here.

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean by $C_0$?

Comment: Paul, please edit the question making explicit what $C_0$ is.

Comment: Can you tell us what do you mean by subspace? Linear or topological? With finite dimensions linear spaces, every subspace is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C_0$ denotes functions vanishing at infinity, then it is $C_0(X\setminus Z)$. The other candidate is much too big to be an ideal in $C_0(X)$.

If, on the other hand, $C_0$ denotes compactly supported functions, then Robin Chapman's answer applies.

Comment: This is correct.  $C(X\setminus Z)$ isn't even a Banach algebra, and it will contain many elements that don't come from $C_0(X)$, the most obvious being its unbounded elements.

Comment: Your interpretation of $C_0$ is the one I had in mind.  I kept freaking myself out about what happens near the boundary for no good reason, but it was all a bunch of pointless fuss.  Thanks to both of you for helping me get grounded in reality.

Answer (score 2):

I presume $C_0(X)$ means compactly supported continuous
functions on $X$. So you are asking which compactly supported continuous
functions on $X$ which vanish on $Z$. Now these may not be compactly supported
on $X-Z$ for there may be a point $p$ in $Z$ and a sequence of points $(p_n)$
in converging to $X$ with $f(p_n)\ne0$ but $f(p)=0$. On the other hand there
will be continuous functions on $X-Z$ which don't converge to zero on the boundary.
So neither $C(X-Z)$ nor $C_0(X-Z)$ is correct!

Comment: I think $C_0(X)$ means continuous functions vanishing at infinity, that is, which are arbitrarily small outside of sufficiently large compact subsets.